# How can I create Jenkins view that displays only currently running jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2

I wan to make a Jenkins (2.x) view that displays only currently running jobs (or something very close to that).

Please note that I am talking about an instance >1000 defined jobs where at a single moment we expect to have 5-30 running ones.

Looking at the node/works sidebar is far from ideal as it involves scrolling a narrow column with a height of >20 screens,... almost impossible to get a "clean view" of the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [View Job Filters plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=44302601#content/view/44302601) which allow you to filter job view, 
Filter by Build Statuses of Currently building jobs.